# Hokuyo utm-30lx restart command

Tags: hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello :)

I have a Hokuyo utm-30lx mounted on the patrolbot from mobilerobots, it was working quite nice with a 12V external power supply, then I decided to connect it to the 12V PWR right power I/O bay  and suddenly I got no power from the bay and I had to turn the 12V power on again from the LCD panel. But, suddenly my computer could not read the device /dev/ttyAMC0

I have tried with to connect it under  windows and it is the same problem.

Just wondering whether there is a way to find out the error and make the device work again

I am using ROSARIA in ROS.

Is there any command to the laser so I can restart the device?

Cheers :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60368/hokuyo-utm-30lx-restart-command/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ehm, that doesn't sound like a software problem. I don't know your robot, but suddenly no power shouldn't happen (I guess). The only thing I could image if there is a power cycle is that the device switched. Check with `dmesg` if that happened. There is then usually a /dev/ttyACM1 or similar.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1